# Eureka, config and admin in just one service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-boot-admin

I try to run Eureka Server Config Server and Spring Boot Admin Server in one Application. Eureka is working as intended but the Admin App means uri: /applications shows the same content as eureka.

Spring Boot Version 2.2.6, Spring Boot Admin Version 2.2.1

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableEurekaServer
@EnableConfigServer
@EnableAdminServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Server bootstrap.properties

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///${user.home}/m2ulifeconfig/maya-config
spring.cloud.config.server.git.basedir=file:///${user.home}/m2ulifeconfig/maya-config
spring.cloud.config.server.git.force-pull=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.timeout=4
spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations=file:///${user.home}/m2ulifeconfig/maya-config
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8082/config
spring.profiles.active=native
server.port=8082
spring.cloud.config.profile=sit

spring.boot.admin.context-path=/admin
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
endpoint.health.show-details=ALWAYS

eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8082/eureka/
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
```

everything is fine just I have a problem:
 when I use @EnableConfigServer i couldnt see the spring boot admin dashboard means 
 http://localhost:8082/admin/wallboard.

Before adding the @EnableConfigServer:
[image]

After @EnableConfigServer:
[image]

Comment: I wondering if put discovery and config server is a good practice. Do you have some feedback ?